# How to implement OnEnter and OnExit event on ContentControl using Javascript API for Word 2016

Tags: javascript, dom-events, office-js

There are many contentcontrols in a document and I need to find out a way that the cursor is in which content control so that I will select that control and do the operation accordingly.  I think by implementing `onEnter` and `onExit` events for contentcontrols , I can achieve it. But I don't know how to declare and invoke those eventhandlers in JavaScript API. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use a combination of APIs to implement that functionality with the current API set:

1. First add an event handler for the [Document.selectionChanged event](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.selectionchanged.event).
2. Every time the event fires, get the Range object corresponding to the selection in the document, using the [Document.getSelection() API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document).
3. Check the range to see if there's a content control in it, using the [Range.contentControls](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) relationship.

-Michael (PM for add-ins)

Answer (score 3):

Good question! We do have an onEnter event for content controls (we call it binding.selectionChanged. We also have a binding.dataChanged event who gets triggered if the user changes the content and exits the content control

so an alternative solution to what Michael proposed is to create bindings for each content control in the document and then register for such events.

you can achieve this by:
1. traversing the content control collection.(use [body.contentControls](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body?product=word) collection)
2. for each content control, grab or set the title and use it to create a binding by named item. check the [bindings.addFromNamedItem](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfromnameditemasync?product=word)  method.
3. on the callBack  make sure to subscribe to the selectionChanged (or DataChanged)  for the binding.
the create binding code and register to the events will look like this:

```js
function CreateCCSelectionChangedEvent() {
        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("TitleOfTheContentControl", { id: 'Binding01' }, function (result) {
            if (result.status == 'succeeded') {
                result.value.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, handler);
            }
        });
       
    }

    function handler() {
       console.log("Event Triggered!");
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Michael,
My company tried this approach a few years ago in a VSTO addin. It ended badly. The problem is the number of events you have to handle is horrific. The performance penalty is drastic and grows with the document size.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31991016)