# ContentControlOnEnter, ContentControlOnExit alternative for office js API

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-contentcontrol, office-js-helpers

For VSTO Add-In Application we do have `ContentControlOnEnter` and `ContentControlOnExit` events, to perform post change operation of `ContentControl`

But, I can't see any such events in office JS API

Do, we have any other way to achieve similar functionality, my goal is to detect changes of `ContentControl` and update into pane of Add-in immediately, right now we have to refresh UI manually to update changes of ContentControls to UI, which is big usability drawback for us.

Please suggest any options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this question was asked previously please check the answer here [How to implement OnEnter and OnExit event on ContentControl using Javascript API for Word 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704444/how-to-implement-onenter-and-onexit-event-on-contentcontrol-using-javascript-api/36724280#36724280)

Comment: I think its a good alternative solution, where we need to  register events for each ContentControl in the document, but seems it might be costly solution, as in my case we can have hundreds of ContentControls, So, was looking for similar solution like VSTO where office JS can manage any ContentControl event, but seems its not available as of now, Thanks for this solution, It will help until then.

Comment: FWIW I have tried this with documents holding thousands of content controls